# 12 V PWM fan and Wemos D1 Mini - ground loop?

Tags: arduino, pwm, esp8266, fan

Newbie here.

I'm trying to power a 12 V 4-wire fan and a [Wemos D1 Mini](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1:d1_mini) from the same power source. The aim is to use a [Dallas DS18B20 temp sensor](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temp/DS18B20.pdf) and increase/decrease the fan speed as per the temp range.

Everything works fine when I power the Wemos separately (i.e. via the USB connector) and the fan by a 12 V source, but as soon as I try and run the two from the same power source, I start burning the 18B20 temp sensor.

I suspect a ground loop or something like that - here's a diagram of how I've wired things up:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtuNs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi Calvin. Just a note that you can create a schematic right in the question by clicking the schematic button (or pressing Control+M). On the 18B20, can you label your schematic with the `GND`, `DQ`, and `VDD` pins? Is the connection from Wemos D2 to the fan the `SIGNAL` (tach or RPM output)? Is the resistor shown in the schematic a 4.7k pull-up from `DQ` to positive?

Comment: Start with  a list of specs for each interface and setpoint for 100% and 0% fan with linear range between.

Comment: @Sunny How does that help fixing the problem with destroying his temperature sensors?

Comment: Why type of buck converter are you using?  It seems to have a seperate - pin for the 3.3V output.

Comment: Ok - I think I owe Jay a big thank you for beating me to that schematic! Thanks.

Comment: @JYelton as per Jay's work. It's RPM/tach & PWM. Yes - let me see if I can fix that current label.

Comment: Ah - it's a .47k - obviously that makes a difference.... let me swap it out.

Comment: nope - even with the 4.7k resistor instead of the .47k, the 18b20 still cooks - slowly enough for me to feel it heating up and pull the plug......

Comment: @JRE it's https://www.banggood.com/5Pcs-Mini-DC-DC-9V12V19V-To-3_3V-3A-Buck-Car-Charging-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Module-p-1123529.html

Comment: Is that circuit correct?  I see you have 3.3V connected to "D" directly, and the power to the sensor through a resistor.  I'd expect the opposite - 3.3V straight to the sensor, and a resistor as a pullup on D.

Comment: Ok.  Your circuit is different than I thought.  Take your buck converter (disconnect it from the battery and the rest of your circuit) and measure the resistance from the battery side ground and the output side ground.  If it isn't a dead short circuit you've got a problem.

Comment: ok - buck converter was a dead short there. Went back to my breadboard, and it's all good - I suspect I must start with a clean vero board 'cause I'm obviously doing something wrong there - will report back if I get it soldered up correctly.